# Representing a 10 radix as a $10^k$ radix - How will the arithmetic and representation differ?

Tags: algorithms, number-systems

Hi I am trying to understand how write code that deals with large integers greater than the predefined numeric datatypes (ie much greater than 64 bit integers).

I have observed that most libraries actually take a large base $10$ number and treat it as a base $10^9$ number.

For example take the base 10 number : $12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890$, if I were to represent this a base $10^9$ number, without introducing any new symbols for the digits (like A or $\alpha$) how would the arithmetic work ?

1. Would there be a change in the representation ? **I think no**, because if each digit is between $0$ and $10^9-1$ then the number should look the same as a base 10 number, provide we are still not using any esoteric symbols to denote the digits. **Correct me if I am wrong.**
2. How would the arithmetic work ? For example how would addition and multiplication work ? **How will add and carry work ?** Can some simple examples be shared ? I am really confused about how this works.

Comment: For your example number, don't you need to introduce new symbols to represent $234567890_{10}$ and $345678901_{10}$ (and more) in the new base?

Comment: @peterwhy Well given a $10^9$ base you could argue that `233` could be the symbol for $234$ th digit in the $10^9$ number system.

Answer (score 2):

1. Of course , the value of the number does not depend on the base $b$ we choose to write it down in a base-$b$-system
2. Essentially , adding would work blockwise the carry is the sum (+ an eventual carry) modulo $10^9$. Mutltiplication would work analogue to the way it works in base $10$ , but the calculation would become really messy (Basically we would treat the blocks as digits , carries are still taken modulo $10^9$). So, it is better to apply the calculations in base $10$ and transform the result into the base-$10^9$-system which is easy.

Answer (score 1):

> I have observed that most libraries actually take a large base 10
> number and treat it as a base $10^9$ number.

This is because computers work internally in binary.  It requires 30 bits (which can represent a number between 0 and 1,073,741,823) to represent each base-billion “digit”.  This easily fits in the widely-available [32-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit_computing) integer type, with two bits left over.  A computer program *could* store decimal digits individually [using 4 bits per digit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal), but this would allow only 8 digits instead of 9 to fit in a 32-bit integer.

> Would there be a change in the representation?

If you mean the human-visible representation, probably not.  It's impractical for a person to learn and distinguish a billion different digits, so most likely we'd continue spelling each base-billion “digit” with 9 decimal digits.  Maybe add some punctuation to emphasize the fact that the numbers are grouped in units of 9, like:

```
000012345:678901234:567890123:456789012:345678901:234567890
```

If you mean the computer-internal binary representation, then yes, there is a difference.  Representing the above number as a sequence of 32-bit integers storing base-billion digits gives:

```
00000000000000000011000000111001 00101000011101110011010111110010 
00100001110110010101000011001011 00011011001110100000110000010100 
00010100100110101010010000110101 00001101111110110011100011010010
```

While representing the individual decimal digits in binary gives:

```
0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 0000
0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 0000
0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 0000
0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 0000
0001 0010 0011 0100 0101 0110 0111 1000 1001 0000
```

> How would the arithmetic work ? For example how would addition and multiplication work ? How will add and carry work ?

You just use the standard elementary-school algorithms for base-$b$ addition and multiplication, setting $b = 10^9$.

Addition is column by column, from least-significant to most-significant digit.  If any column sum is $\ge b$, then subtract $b$ from the sum, and carry 1 to the next column.

Comment: Unrelated to the original question: why not just use all 32 bits and create the blocks as unsigned and store the actual sign in a separate variable. Why leave out that 1 bit for the sign in all blocks ?

Comment: My intuition says it uses 9 digits because the algorithm wants to avoid overflows. Since addition and other operations will potentially happen in 32 bit blocks. Don't know, **but correct me if I am wrong.**

Comment: @ng.newbie: You *could* store the sign in a separate variable.  I just wanted to point out that this format *can* use the extra two bits for special purposes.  Since that seems to have just caused confusion, I removed the examples.